# What are the advantages of "full" sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients

Why would a normal user want to launch a node in any mode other than "light" , does full or fast give any advantages in sending transactions ?

Is there any difference between transaction sent from full and light nodes ?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/what-is-geths-light-sync-and-why-is-it-so-fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between sending a transaction from a light client or full node in terms of speed of transaction, as far as I know.

By hosting a full node however you are helping expand the ethereum network. Ethereum has come such long way over the last year that I think most of the benefits of running a full node no longer exist. If you did it its mainly because you are interested in Ethereum and want to participate.

[What are the valuable benefits of having a node?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/what-are-the-valuable-benefits-of-having-a-node)

[Can incentive be provided for non-mining Ethereum nodes?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/can-incentive-be-provided-for-non-mining-ethereum-nodes)